# Why wont the title in my Toolbar show?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-toolbar

The title in my toolbar is not showing.

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.mddri_.myeats.main._MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:title="@string/app_label"
    android:titleTextColor="@color/textColor"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_main"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    />
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"/>
```

I don't reference the toolbar in my java code, but I can show you that if you need it. It seems like I should be able to set the title of the toolbar just by using `android:title="desired_title"`. The Toolbar is showing, It is the correct color and size, but it doesn't show the title.

Comment: try getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);

Answer (score 1):

Use the following.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
```

Comment: This code gives me an error at `setSupportActionBar(topToolBar); `    `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mddri_.myeats/com.mddri_.myeats.main._Main‌​Activity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.`

Comment: As the error explains, you did not set the default actionbar to false before you attempt to set the toolbar. Declare a theme for the activity using a style with `windowActionBar` set to false, or a style that inherits a parent with NoActionBar (e.g. `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`). Look up on the error, there are tons of it having answers to it. :]